# Always have default values in function declaration

Tags: php

I've got just one question -> is it good to have all parameters defined with default values in a function. I think it is a bad practice but I have a little argument with my colleague.

So is either:

```
public function getTestByUser($int_user_id, $limit, $offset)
```

or

`public function getTestByUser($int_user_id = 0, $limit = 0, $offset = null)`

better / nicer?

And why do you think so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it will save you from getting unintended results - however also will hide the processing errors,, which might teach you lots of things.

Comment: For calling function i think 

   ` public function getTestByUser($int_user_id = 0, $limit = 0, $offset = null)`

This is better with **Default Argument Value** Because when we do not pass variable value as function parameter it takes default value

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your needs. Using default values for function variables is actually not a bad practice.

You shouldn't variable types as names. You can use PHP7's scalar type declaration feature.

e.g:

```
public function getTestByUser(int $userId, int $limit = 0, int $offset = null)
```

Dont' forget to add `declare(strict_types=1);` to top of your php file. Using strictly defined variable types make your code more solid.

Comment: I agree with your point but why should a userId be 0? I'd rather take the "processing" error in calling the function wrongly instead of getting results which I dont know of where they're coming from

Comment: Right, you shouldn't use a default value for a userId. I fixed the code. Don't use default value if a varaible mandatory and don't work without a value (e.g: user id)